# Encryption status in sys.dm_database_encryption_keys not consistent with sys.databases

Tags: sql-server, tde

If I query `sys.dm_database_encryption_keys`, it comes back with an `encryption_state` of `3` (encrypted), `percent_complete` of `0`.  If I query `sys.databases`, the `is_encrypted` column has a value of 0 (not encrypted).  These two seem to counter each other to me.

Is the database encrypted?  `sys.dm_database_encryption_keys` says so, but `is_encrypted` in `sys.databases` disagrees.

Under database properties, the property `Encryption Enabled` is false.

I'm confused.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems you've got a case where a DB got encrypted by the SQL server automatically, such as in case of tempdb, once Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) was enabled. I am seeing exactly same case in my test instance of SQL Server 2012 with tempdb. 
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049%28SQL.100%29.aspx): *The tempdb system database will be encrypted if any other database on the instance of SQL Server is encrypted by using TDE.*

**is_encrypted = 0** I believe reflects the fact that DB was encrypted automatically, not by issuing ALTER command. 
Here is what [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) says about this parameter: *Indicates whether the database is encrypted (reflects the state last set by using the ALTER DATABASE SET ENCRYPTION clause).*

**percent_complete = 0** is expected when there is no ongoing encryption. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677274.aspx): *Percent complete of the database encryption state change. This will be 0 if there is no state change.*

**encryption_state = 3** looks to be the ultimate hint in answering the question. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677274.aspx): *Indicates whether the database is encrypted or not encrypted, 3 = Encrypted.*

[MSDN TDE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) page itself suggests to use **sys.dm_database_encryption_keys** to verify if DB is encrypted or not.

And finally, here is a really handy script from [John Magnabosco's post](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/transparent-data-encryption/) showing which DBs are encrypted with TDE and which are not (encryption_state = 3 is the teller):

```
SELECT
    db.name,
    db.is_encrypted,
    dm.encryption_state,
    dm.percent_complete,
    dm.key_algorithm,
    dm.key_length
FROM
    sys.databases db
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_database_encryption_keys dm
        ON db.database_id = dm.database_id;
GO
```

Hopefully this makes it less confusing now.

Comment: I know this is old, but your comment regarding tempdb is a good hint.   MSDN says that you need to RESTART SQL-Server after disabling encryption on ALL databases.   I ran into this myself.  tempdb showed a weird state after disabling encryption on my Adventureworks sample.  The MSDN trouble-shooting doc helps resync the state, and lists 3 assumptions... first one being "restarting SQL Server"  I did that, and tempdb status cleared up.